# How do I disable some of these things in Eclipse? It's a lot meatier than I'd like

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

For one, I don't like it auto closing my parentheses and brackets, I prefer to do that myself.

Also, I don't like how all this crap pops up all the time. Is there a way to disable these hints or whatever?

Comment: *"Also, I don't like how all this crap pops up all the time."*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Preferences->Java->Editor->Typing.